# Problem with deleting item out of cart when the same item with diffrent size is in cart already

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, shopping-cart

## Problem with removing items out of cart.

> When pressing the generated delete button under the item the first item wil be removed out of the cart but then the other item with diffrent size but same product glitches. it start showing errors just like it also removed the ones with the different size.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
    if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
    {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
        if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
        {
            $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'item_id'           =>  $_POST["Productid"],
                'item_name'         =>  $_POST["Productnaam"],
                'item_price'        =>  $_POST["prijs"],
                'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["hoeveelheid"],
                'item_size'         =>  $_POST["maat"]
            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        }
        else
        {
            $item_array_size = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_size");
            if(!in_array($_POST["maat"], $item_array_size)){
                $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                $item_array = array(
                    'item_id'           =>  $_POST["Productid"],
                    'item_name'         =>  $_POST["Productnaam"],
                    'item_price'        =>  $_POST["prijs"],
                    'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["hoeveelheid"],
                    'item_size'     =>  $_POST["maat"]
                );
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            }
            else
            {
            for($i=0; $i < count($item_array_id); $i++){
                if($item_array_id[$i] == $_POST['Productid']){
                    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$i]['item_quantity'] +=$_POST["hoeveelheid"];
                }
            }
            }
        }   
    }
}
else
{
    $count = 0;
    $item_array = array();
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $item_array;
}
if(isset($_POST["delete"])) <--- Delete button
{
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
    {
        if($values["item_id"] == $_POST["id"] && $values["item_size"] == $_POST["maat"])
        {
            unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Delete button:

```
      <form method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="maat" value="<?php echo $values["item_size"];?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $values["item_id"];?>">
       <button  type="submit" name="delete">( <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Verwijderen )</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] . Using the $count as the key is not the best solution when you add items to the cart. I would use a "unique" identifier like the productID which is already available in $_POST. Then try deleting the product in the cart by it's productID

Comment: alright il give it a shot :)

Comment: i can't get it to work it keeps glitching out